# Why is Integer.MIN_VALUE failing on Balanced Binary Tree? What's the bug?

Tags: java, recursion, tree

https://leetcode.com/problems/balanced-binary-tree/

> Given a binary tree, determine if it is height-balanced.
>
> For this problem, a height-balanced binary tree is defined as a binary
> tree in which the depth of the two subtrees of every node never differ
> by more than 1.

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
        
        int ret = getLevel(root);
        if(ret < 0)
            return false;
        
        return true;
        
    }
    public int getLevel(TreeNode node) {

        if(node == null)
            return 0;

        int l = getLevel(node.left);
        int r = getLevel(node.right);
        if(Math.abs(l - r) > 1)
            return -99;
            
        return Math.max(l + 1, r + 1);
    }
}
```

This code is Accepted.
**However if I replace -99 with Integer.MIN_VALUE, my code fails.  What's the bug?**

e.g.

> Input: [1,2,null,3,null,4,null,5]
>
> Output: true
>
> Expected: false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is failing because of integer arithmetic which is overflowing.  The following code snippet will demonstrate this:

```
int val = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
System.out.println(val);
val -= 3;
System.out.println(val);
```

**Output:**

```
-2147483648
2147483645
```

Now consider what is happening in your actual code:

```
int l = getLevel(node.left);
// l == -2147483648 == Integer.MIN_VALUE assuming your base case is hit
int r = getLevel(node.right);
// assuming positive r, then Math.abs() will return a massively positive number
if (Math.abs(l - r) > 1)
        return -99;
```

In other words, the above `if` statement will be firing `true` when it really should have fired `false`.

**Solution:**

If you modify the `getLevel()` method to the following, you should skirt the problems you are having:

```
public int getLevel(TreeNode node) {
    if(node == null)
        return 0;

    int l = getLevel(node.left);
    int r = getLevel(node.right);
    if ( (l < 0 ^ r < 0) || Math.abs(l - r) > 1) {
        // you can simply return -1 here, since an actual
        // level should never have a negative value
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        return Math.max(l + 1, r + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is completely oposite, it returns false when it should return true. But it happens only in very special situations,see my answer. Your case doesn't hurt actually.

Answer (score 0):

It may fail under some circumstances due to overflow. If `l` is zero and r is `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, `l-r` is actually negative because it overflows. As a result, the condition will fail and the next statement returns max of `MIN_VALUE+1` and `zero+1`.